xRDP/XORG Login fails for other users
Im currently providing a physical ubuntu machine which should be used as a remote machine.
I don't have any problems connection to it from a windows machine, but for others user the login mask ends up in a blue screen after putting in the credentials.
The setup was really basic - was configured as in written in most guides.
Downloaded following packages:
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo apt-get install xfce4

Added the window manager to the starting file
echo xfce4-session > ~/.xsession

Allowed any connection to the port:
sudo ufw allow 3389

In addition i created a group with all the users, and in the xrdp config file marked that at every login the group needs to be checked -> sesman.ini
AllowRootLogin=true
TerminalServersUsers=<groupname>
TerminalServersAdminss=<admingroupname>
AlwaysGroupCheck=true

Where I need to look for solving this problem? Do I need to add more to a certain config file? Has anyone a similar issue and could help me?
Thanks in advance!

This helped me, to solve the problem:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475045/oh-no-something-has-gone-wrong-ubuntu-23-04-xrdp-xfce-desktop-google
Also these commands:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo reboot


Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that link-only answers are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.
